# Bundling Java libraries with a DB2 Java stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, java-stored-procedures, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

Creating a DB2 Java stored procedure using IBM Data Studio, I have some libraries that are required in the classpath.
I'm running Data Studio in a VM, and deploying remotely to my DB2 server in a Cloud instance.

How do I bundle up the jars with my stored procedure?

Comment: do you mean how to execute the Stored Procedure in Java application?

Comment: I [guess](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dstudio/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.datatools.routines.bottomup.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcjavaspscreatedjavaprojs.html) so, then how do you deploy a Java stored procedure and it's dependencies in the Java project (_not Data project_) to be able to run the SP from DB2?

Comment: you need to understand 2 things: 1. Execute a stored procedure from Java Application, and 2. Create a stored procedure with Java language.  You're looking [the 2nd one](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg245945.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying the stored procedure to the server:

[image: Deploy stored procedure with Data Studio: Deploy Options]

make sure you click **Next** instead of Finish to get to the second screen:

[image: Deploy stored procedure with Data Studio: Routine Options]

and there, in the **Compile options:** field append your dependencies using the **`-classpath`** command-line option.

**Note:** the [`-cp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5172507/341929) shorthand option will not work!

Comment: I tried this and by configuring the class path it lets me deploy the store procedure.  I checked the jar made and it doesn't contain the jar library, so my code fails with NoClassDefFoundError